# How to make windows compatible PPT on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: windows, presentation

I need to create a ppt in Ubuntu but I need the themes of Microsoft PowerPoint or you can say windows compatible presentation. Could you please suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: you can try [kingsoft office](http://wps-community.org/download.html) for linux. although it's still in alpha, it's usable now

Answer (score 2):

**LibreOffice** comes installed in Ubuntu, the presentation program is called **Impress**.

You can also open Microsoft PowerPoint files, and save your work in PowerPoint format for people still locked into Microsoft products. Alternatively, you can use the built-in exporter to create Flash (.swf) versions of your presentations.

https://www.libreoffice.org/features/impress/

Answer (score 0):

Use **Impress** which comes installed with LibreOffice

Command to launch Impress in Ubuntu:

```
loffice --impress
```

or

```
libreoffice --impress
```

or

```
loimpress
```